# Define method type for meta dynamically created method

Tags: sorbet

I'm using `graphql-ruby`, and I'd really like to be able to type the dynamic methods that created for things like `arguments`.

Small example:

```rb
class Test

  argument :first_argument, String
  argument :secondArgument, String, as: second_argument, required: false

  def method
    puts first_argument.length # this is okay
    puts second_argument.length # this is a problem, because it can be nil
  end
end
```

I've tried to define these by doing:

```rb
  # ...
  first_argument = T.let(nil, String)
  second_argument = T.let(nil, T.nilable(String))
```

which doesn't seem to work. I also did

```rb
  #...
  sig { returns(String) }
  def first_argument; ""; end
  sig { returns(T.nilable(String)) }
  def second_argument; end
```

which *works*, but is not overly pretty. Is there a nicer way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is some nascent, experimental support for typing methods declared by meta programming like this: https://sorbet.org/docs/metaprogramming-plugins

In this case, you might define a plugin file like:

```
# argument_plugin.rb

# Sorbet calls this plugin with command line arguments similar to the following:
# ruby --class Test --method argument --source "argument :first_argument, String"
# we only care about the source here, so we use ARGV[5]
source = ARGV[5]
/argument[( ]:([^,]*?), ([^,]*?)[) ]/.match(source) do |match_data|
  puts "sig {return(#{match_data[2]})}" # writes a sig that returns the type
  puts "def #{match_data[1]}; end"      # writes an empty method with the right name
end
```

I've only included the "getter" for the argument here, but it should be simple to go ahead and write out the sig for the setter method as well. You'd also want to handle all variants of the `argument` method as I've only handled the one with `Symbol, Type` arguments. For what it's worth, I'm not sure if the "source" passed in to your plugin would be normalized with parens or not, so I've made the regex match either. I also suspect that this will not work if you pass in the symbol names as variables instead of literals.

We then use a YAML file to tell Sorbet about this plugin.

```
# triggers.yaml

ruby_extra_args:
  # These options are forwarded to Ruby
  - '--disable-gems' # This option speeds up Ruby boot time. Use it if you don't need gems
triggers:
  argument: argument_plugin.rb # This tells Sorbet to run argument.rb when it sees a call to `argument`
```

Run Sorbet and pass in the yaml config file as the argument for `--dsl-plugins`:

```
❯ srb tc --dsl-plugins triggers.yaml ... files to type check ...
```

Comment: The "metaprogramming-plugins" link is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd really like to be able to type the dynamic methods that created for things like arguments

Sorbet doesn't support typing dynamic methods like that. But they do provide a [`T::Struct`](https://sorbet.org/docs/tstruct) class that has similar functionality. I did something similar last week for my project and I'll describe what I did below. If `T::Struct` doesn't work for you, an alternative is writing some code to generate the Sigs that you'd write manually.

My approach is using [`T::Struct`](https://sorbet.org/docs/tstruct) as the wrapper for “arguments” class. You can define args as props in a `T::Struct` like following:

- `const` for arguments that don’t change
- `prop` for arguments that may change
- Use `default` to provide a default value when no value is given
- Use `T.nilable` type for arguments that can be nil

Building on top of the vanilla T::Struct, I also add support for “maybe”, which is for args that is truly optional and can be nil. IE: when a value is not passed in, it should not be used at all. It is different from using `nil` as default value because when a value is passed in, it can be `nil`. If you’re interested in this “maybe” component, feel free to DM me.